# save all tr elements of a table with checkbox and send it to the controller , in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and now stuck in a serious problem. it is for me, very serious
I need to load a view with a list of meetings (which is loading fine) in html , I have added a checkbox to each row also. Now I need to save to the database ,only the checked values. But the controller is returning null when posting.. Really stuck and cant find a solution.
Pls see code below which I have done

Model

```
public class aMeet
{
    public List<AcceptedRecords> amList { get; set; }

    public static List<AcceptedRecords> GetamList()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();    
        List<AcceptedRecords> resultlist = new List<AcceptedRecords>();

        using (cmd)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT  Line_code,person_code,person_address from tbl where meeting_code =859489;
            ds = cmd.ExecuteDataSet();
        }
        if (!Utils.IsDataSetEmpty(ds))
        {
            AcceptedRecords tpmApp;
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                tpmApp = new AcceptedRecords();
                tpmApp = tpmApp.LoadRecords(row);
                resultlist.Add(tpmApp);
            }
        }

        return resultlist;
    }
}
```

Model

```
 public class AcceptedRecords
{
    public int line_Code { get; set; }
    public string person_Name { get; set; }
    public string person_Address { get; set; }
    public bool extra_checked { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model projct.Models.aRecs
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddRecord","Home"))
```

{

```
         <table id="tbl" style ="width:100%"   cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="race-fields">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:500px">line code</th>
                            <th style="width:100px">name</th>
                            <th style="width:500px">address</th>
                            <th style="width:500px">extra</th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>

           <tbody>
             <tr>

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.amList.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr class="EvenRow">
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.amList[i].line_Code)          </td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.amList[i].person_name)  </td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.amList[i].person_address)  </td>
                                                  <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.amList[i].extra_checked) </td>

                    </tr>
                }

              </tr> 
              <tr>
                <span>                                    
                <input type="submit" Value ="Save"/>                             
                </span>
              </tr>
           </tbody>

      </table>
```

}

Controller

```
   [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult AddRecord(List<aMeet> spm)
    {
        if (spm == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("No Parameters passed to Create");

                   int? appID = 0;
        return Json(appID);
    }
}
```

--- It Is triggering to controller on Save but model [spm] is null.
How to get this corrected. Here I need to save to database the tr elements that are checked. Please request any help. I have tried a lot of things but the model is always null/
Many thanks

Comment: Friends please  anyone,,, any help

Comment: How does your `aRecs` class looks like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `aRecs` class has a `amList` property which is a list of `AcceptedRecords`

```
public class aRecs
{
    public List<AcceptedRecords> amList { set; get; } 
}
```

Assuming `line_code` value is a unique (*may be primary key*) to get a record from your corresponding table, In your view, you need to keep the `line_code` property value of each item in amList in a hidden field so that when the form is submitted you will get this value and using that you can query the corresponding record and update it.

```
@model YourNamespaceHere.aRecs

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddRecord","Home"))
{
    <table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.amList.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr class="EvenRow">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.amList[i].line_Code)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.amList[i].person_Name) </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.amList[i].extra_checked)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.amList[i].line_Code)
             </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
    <input  type="submit"/>
}
```

And in your HttpPost action, your parameter will be a single object of  `aRecs`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddRecord(aRecs model)
{
    foreach (var item in model.amList)
    {
        var lineCode = item.line_Code;
        var isChecked = item.extra_checked;

        /// get the record using lineCode and update the record.
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thankyou loads.. It worked.. Once again thankyou for your time.